# Close child component from the child component itself

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to close the child component from the child when user click on the close button in child component. Tried to it by passing the state from the child back to the parent but it's not working. What have i done wrong here?

> Parent

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    }
  {

  closeComponent = () => {
      this.setState({
          visible: false
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
       {
         this.state.visible &&
         <Child closeComponent={this.closeComponent} />
       }
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

> Child

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { View, Button } from 'native-base';

import styles from './ChildStyles.js';

export const Child = ({ closeComponent }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.Container}>
      <Button style={styles.Btn} onClick={() => closeComponent}>
        <Text style={styles.BtnText}>Close</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `arrow function` in child is incorrect. Also native-base Button doesn't have an `onClick` but an `onPress` handler. It should be

```
  <Button style={styles.Btn} onPress={() => closeComponent()}>
    <Text style={styles.BtnText}>Close</Text>
  </Button>
```

Comment: Check the updated answer, you need to use onPress instead of onClick